# Global dimension of quiver algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Given a finite quiver $Q$, let $Y(Q)$ be the set of (isomorphism classes of) algebra $kQ/I$ (with admissible ideal $I$) that have finite global dimension.
For example in case $Q$ is acyclic, all algebras have this property and in case $Q$ contains a loop no algebras have this property.
Now assume $Q$ has no loops and is not acyclic (I guess in this case there are always infinitely many algebras of infinite global dimension of the form $KQ/I$).

Questions:

1. Is there a classification of quivers where $Y(Q)$ is finite? This is for example true in case $Q$ is a circle with 1 arrow between neighboring points.
2. For which $Q$ is a classification of algebras in $Y(Q)$ known?
3. For which $Q$ is there a unique algebra with largest finite global dimension? This is for example true for $Q$ a circle and I would expect also in case of the quiver of the Schur algebra of finite representation type.